# Gaussian iterative curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a data (**x** vs. **y** (averaged)) as shown in the image with the points and error bars being the mean and the deviation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW9KA.jpg)

I am trying to fit the best possible gaussian curve to my data but this is only best fit I am getting by using fitgaussian.m function. I have looked into the methods that use iterative gaussian fitting of a sequence of two or more Gaussians but how do I implement it in Matlab?. I am looking to combine two or more gaussian curves to fit my data. I also want (force the starting point) the curve to start at the value " **2.5** " without altering its shape to the best.

Comment: You can add some repeated values of 2.5 to your data to force the curve start at 2.5

Comment: I am looking for iterative gaussian fitting?. Does the previous question  " How to fit a gaussian to data in matlab/octave? " do the iterative fitting of a sequence of two or more Gaussians?